# How to link to libraries using gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, makefile

I installed some encryption software called libntru.
The header files are installed in `/usr/include/libntru` and the file I would like to include from this directory is `ntru.h`.  The compiled library is installed to `/usr/lib/libntru.so`.

In my makefile, I use gcc's `-L` and `-l` flags to link to the library as such `-L/usr/lib -lntru`, however in my project, I get a compiler error at the line `#include <ntru.h>`.

How can I link to this library?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check on the instructions with the software; there's at least a chance you're supposed to write one of:

```
#include <libntru/ntru.h>
#include "libntru/ntru.h"
```

If that's the case, you won't need to specify anything on the command line to find the headers (no `-I` option).  If you're supposed to write just:

```
#include <ntru.h>
#include "ntru.h"
```

Then you need to add `-I/usr/include/libntru` to the command line.

Note that you probably don't need `-L/usr/lib` on the command line; the compiler will normally look there anyway, but you will need the `-lntru` option to specify the library itself, of course.

Comment: You were right.  A combination of `-lntru` and
`#include <libntru/ntru.h>`
works.  Thanks!